# Google Apps Script toLocaleDateString not work

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-apps

I trying to run in GAS script

```
function test(){
var options = { year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' },
locale="ru-RU",
data= (new Date()).toLocaleDateString(locale, options);

Browser.msgBox(data);
}
```

But google always return same format no matter what i type in locale.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe Apps Script doesn't respond to the advanced parameters of `toLocaleDateString()`.  If you are using HTML in your app, I'd try to make the conversion inside a script tag in the HTML, rather than in the server side `.gs` code.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do it server side you can use `Utilities.formatDate()`.

```
var data = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "Europe/Moscow", "yyyy-MM-dd");
```

[GAS formatDate() documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate-timezone-format)

Comment: This does not convert the date to the correct language  for me.